# Where does Windows Store apps stores its local settings?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Hello fellow programmers,

I am new to Windows 8. Where does Windows Store app's LocalSettings store its serialized file ? I am referring to this one:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings
```

Per WinStore app tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx), I can load and save serialized properties to either roaming settings or local settings. The roaming goes to the cloud, but where exactly does the local setting goes to ? Registry? Isolated file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Look in c:\users\{username}\AppData\Local\Packages\{packageID} where packageID identifies a particular app. In there you'll see a number of folders, and inside the one called Settings you'll see settings.dat. That's where the LocalSettings and RoamingSettings are stored. (Roaming settings are stored locally and sync'd with the cloud, so you aren't hitting the cloud every time you want to retrieve one.)

The LocalState, RoamingState, and TempState folders alongside Settings are where you can store your own files if what you want to store in settings gets too complicated for key-value pairs.

Comment: Yeap, the settings.dat is what I am looking for. Thanks !.