# In UWP, where should I save user data?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I made an UWP app for Microsoft Store. However, user data automatically saved in the LocalState folder will be deleted every time the app is updated. I want the data to be retained after every updating, so I'm trying to suggest the users to save their data by themselves in the Document folder or somewhere to avoid their data deleted, but I don't want to bother them. Where should I save user data?

The roaming folder will be unable to use in future and I don't want to use Azure because of its fee.

Comment: The common approach is to store the data in some remote location, like for example in the cloud. If you think Azure is to expensive, you'll have to find a cheaper storage solution.

Comment: [Roaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#roaming-data) ?

Comment: Something is strange in your issue...
I develop and maintain many apps on Windows Store (privates and publics) and the data stored in LocalStorage aren't deleted when an update is applied.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The common approach is to store the data in some remote location, like for example in the cloud. You would typically use a service of some kind to request and save the data.

If you think Azure is to expensive, you'll have to find a cheaper storage solution. The principle is the same regardless of which storage provider you use.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077), roaming data is (or at least will be) deprecated. The recommended replacement is Azure App Service.

Comment: It mentioned PSR is depricated. Are you sure if roaming (I understand it as [RoamingState](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099365/1997232)) and PSR is the same thing?

Comment: Publishing private data to someone's else server is not always a good idea. Specially since it requires internet access. A local file is a must for many reasons.

Comment: PCR is what backs the roaming functionality for UWP apps. The main drawback of storing data locally is mentioned in the question.